# Liability Insurance - What if you break the law?

Tags: uk

Are there any insurance policies out there that cover you if you have an accident while say, jumping a red light or cycling the wrong way on a one-way road?

Comment: Given the tag, this question is specific to insurance law in the UK and has only a tangential connection with cycling.  I'd suggest it might be more on-topic for law.stackexchange.com

Comment: I could answer this question for the USA but not elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 'liability insurance' is for damage you do to others, and 'personal insurance' is for damage you sustain. So your title suggests you want cover for, eg, running into a Rolls Royce when jumping a red light, while your question body suggests 'what happens to me if I go round the barriers and ride under a train?'

It's almost impossible to find insurance for illegal activities in general, and often even for non-causal/incidental minor infringements. That makes sense if you start from the extreme cases "I want to insure my house before I set it on fire" or "I want to buy life insurance before I kill myself" and work backwards until you find a nice easily-defended place to draw the line... "it's illegal so you're not insured".

Your normal cover on just about anything ([per Matt](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/63897/7044)) should give you some liability insurance and it may well pay out if your infringements are not considered relevant. But if it goes to court you will almost certainly lose because the other side will be very keen to point out the law-breaking.

For personal cover it's harder. There's are lots of UK articles about how to invalidate your car insurance by breaking trivial laws, like [this one](https://parkinsurance.co.uk/will-invalidate-car-insurance-complete-list-2018/) but they are all very careful to say "might invalidate" or "may cause insurer to deny". So if you, say, are on the wrong side of the road, hit a pot-hole and go over the handlebars you could well be covered because you would probably have been hurt even if you were obeying the law. But if you hit that Roller above and wreck your bike you're unlikely to be covered for anything and Murphy's Law says the Roller will have a QC behind the wheel.

Comment: For those outside the Commonwealth, a QC is a Queen's Counsel, a senior barrister (trial lawyer).

Comment: Actually, the house fire example isn't a great one. Assuming you own your house outright (i.e., it's not collateral against a mortgage) and you don't damage anybody else's property, I don't think it's illegal to burn it down. You're certainly allowed to burn other items of your property and I don't see why houses would be any different. The illegality in burning your house (or anything else) down and then claiming on insurance is that you would have to claim that you didn't deliberately (or probably even grossly negligently) start the fire, and that false claim would constitute fraud.

Comment: Let me clarify the house fire example. It's only fraud if you lie about setting it on fire, rather than simply saying "you said you'd pay out if it burned down, and it burned down". Insurance companies ask that stuff now as a result of people actually doing that. (they still do that, hence the regular trials and convictions)

Comment: Unless you have really shady insurance, you have to be doing something felonious or really bad for insurance not to pay out for liability. Virtually every car crash involves at least one law broken, usually multiple. If car insurance never paid out, no one would buy it.

Comment: @whatsisname sadly either Aotearoa has a lot of really shady insurance companies or your idea doesn't apply there. There were a whole heap of claims denied after the Christchurch quakes for tiny little detail type violations. Insurance companies can and do argue that what you think is an irrelevant legal technicality is sufficiently causal to justify not paying out. And as always, you're free to take them to court and usually within a decade you'll get a decision.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to check the exact wording of your insurance policy. It's fairly common for insurance policies to have exclusions such as this (from [Wiggle's policy](https://d3a6agorgwj4uy.cloudfront.net/Wiggle_UK_Policy_Wording.pdf)):

> any event which results from Your deliberate act or omission and which could reasonably have been expected by You having regards to the nature and circumstances of such act or omission;

So if you accidentally jump a red light then you would be covered, but if it's deliberate then probably you wouldn't be. Note that it's not the illegality of jumping a red light that triggers this exclusion, it's the fact that jumping a red light could reasonably be expected to cause a collision.

Answer (score 1):

I live in New Zealand. As a rule home contents insurance has cover for public liability, so this cover would be available if you had an accident while riding your bike.   I believe the UK is very similar, but as always, you need to read the fine print of the insurance documentation.

If you do not have liability cover, specific cover for your bicycle(s) should include it.  Again read the policy document carefully, and if you do not understand it, ask the insurer.

If you belong to a club, especially if they are  a member of a national body, and a riding as apart of an organized event, you are probably covered, but there are often exclusions (like if you prang into another member its not covered)

In many cases there are restrictions and exclusions - for instance its common to exclude any form of racing to time trials.

As far as the things you list, insurance is cover for unforeseeable accidental damage and loss. Insurers are probably within there rights under the policy to decline such a claim as the loss in those situations is entirely foreseeable. They tend to deal with such things on a case by case basis, and the outcome is not always to the claimants liking.